# Can not open a JVM which is opened using a batch which is opened using another batch

Tags: java, batch-file, jvm, dos

I am trying to open a batch file which is opened by another batch file which is supposed to start a JVM but when I try to open it all I get is a cmd prompt with path to my desktop in it.

This is the content of the batch file I use to open the JVM. (run.bat which is in the same folder as myJar.jar)

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" -Xmx2048M -Xms2048M -jar myJar.jar
```

And this is the line I use to open the previos batch file. (Which is on my desktop)

```
start /HIGH /MIN "My Folder\run.bat"
```

Can somebody please explain me why it doesn't work and how I can fix it?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I have tried to open another bat which just had echo Hi! in it but even that didn't work. Is it even possible to open a .bat using a .bat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I type your command, I also get a new window. But I notice that the title of the window is `My Folder\run.bat`. This is because if the `start` command sees a parameter with quotes, it assumes that it is the title of the new window.

Try `start /HIGH /MIN "This is my title" "My Folder\run.bat"`

Comment: Lavinio your solution worked! Thank you very mush for helping me out!

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like the .bat file with "start ... My folder\run.bat" is on the desktop ... and "myJar.jar" isn't ;)

SUGGESTION:

1. [Right-click] your "start" .bat file, "Properties", "Start In" = "My Folder"
2. Verify "myJar.bar" is in "My Folder"
3. Try again